# Status of $BQP^{NP},NP^{BQP}$

Tags: complexity-theory, reference-request, complexity-classes

The relation between $BQP$ and $NP$ is an open problem, while it seems that $BQP$ is somewhat lower for $NP$ than the other way round. Is the status of lowness of these problems known?

Comment: bkg helpful, eg technical defn of "lower"?